# Imagespan remove a character already present in textview

Tags: android-layout, android-view, android

I have a little problem with ImageSpan, i would like to insert in a spannable string an icon in first position of text view.

Textview will render Like this : icon+HELLO+hello

My code :

```
text += df.format(seconds);
// text += "."+Integer.toString(milliseconds);
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.mb_ic_chrono );

SpannableString label = new SpannableString("");
SpannableString data = new SpannableString("");
label = new SpannableString("Temps \n");
label.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 0, label.length(), 0);

data = new SpannableString(text);
data.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1f), 0, data.length(), 0);

SpannableString sentence=new SpannableString(TextUtils.concat(label,data));
sentence.setSpan(new ImageSpan(icon,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),0,1 , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
setText(sentence,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I don't understand why when i add the image span before the first character, it is deleted, i would like add the icon at start of string not delete the first character.

Comment: A possible workaround is add a space before text: " Temps \n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround is add a space before text: " Temps \n" or create a intermediate SpannableString with ImageSpan set.

```
text += df.format(seconds);
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher );

SpannableString label = new SpannableString("Temps \n");
label.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 0, label.length(), 0);

SpannableString data = new SpannableString(text);
data.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1f), 0, data.length(), 0);

SpannableString iconTextSpan = new SpannableString(" ");
//if you have a context
iconTextSpan.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context,icon,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),0,1 , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//else
//iconTextSpan.setSpan(new ImageSpan(icon,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),0,1 , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

SpannableString sentence = new SpannableString(TextUtils.concat(iconTextSpan,label,data));
setText(sentence,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, I use this  after ask question before your answer, i didn't find an other way. How other people can create chat with emoticons ^^, that is the question, i don't believe they add spaces before all words.